# Font Awesome Icons with colours more than one

Tags: css, font-awesome

Can I use more than one color for a fontawsome icon?

For example, can I do this when I want to use a yellow, black lined and shaded light bulb ***(fa-lightbulb-o)***?

Thank you very much for your help already.

Comment: not in any straightforward way. You could extract the SVG markup for an individual icon, edit it in your favorite app (e.g Adobe Illustrator, Sketch, ...), and insert it as inline SVG or as an external `<img>` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that with css, as font awesome is a font, and you can only chose one colour for your font. You can get the svg easily from [this site](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG)